# ASP.NET Labels aren't displaying the expected value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net

I need help on this assignment question:

When user visits the website, it's supposed to display the greeting message “Good Morning” if the time the user visiting is in the morning. If it is afternoon, it should display “Good afternoon”; if it is at night, it should display “Good evening”.

I am a little confused as to why the labels in this ASP.NET website are not displaying the greetings at all.

My code snippet:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" 

CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="Labs_7_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblGreeting" runat="server"/>
    </div>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code behind:

```
Partial Class Labs_7_Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    If DateTime.Now.Hour >= 6 And DateTime.Now.Hour < 12 Then
        lblGreeting.Text = "Good morning"
    ElseIf DateTime.Now.Hour >= 12 And DateTime.Now.Hour < 18 Then
        lblGreeting.Text = "Good afternoon"
    Else
        lblGreeting.Text = "Good evening"
    End If
End Sub
```

I have also tried other variations of this code but the labels are never shown in the browser.

Comment: Try to remove onload="" function. just use empty <body> tag

Comment: Is the "code snippet" the whole markup that you have? Some tags are missing (html, ending body tag).

Comment: Look at `AutoEventWireup`: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324151. I believe that's your problem.

Comment: Thank you @TimMedora. Changing the AutoEventWireup to 'true' solved it. It's very surprising that this was overlooked in my teacher's lecture.

Answer (score 2):

Some part of the ASPX file may be missing. The minimal markup should look like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblGreeting" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`WebForm1` and `WebApplication1` may have different names in your application.

**UPDATE**

The real answer was given by Tim Medora. I missed the fact that `Page_Load` in your code-behind did not have `Handles Me.Load`:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
```

If the `Handles` clause is there, `AutoEventWireup` can be false. Otherwise, it must be true.

Comment: Sorry about that. The Full code is shown in the edited post.